# Dynamic linq query for doing aggregates like sum and average

Tags: asp.net, .net, linq

I am trying to write a single LINQ query to compute aggregates like sum/average/min/max and count. In my app, user selects the aggregate, which will be sent from the UI and stored in a variable. How can I use aggregate dynamically in LINQ query?

Sample query:

```
 var selectedAggregate ="Count";

 var xaxisparam2 = (from b in FiltersList
                  where (--column name--)
                 group b by (--column name--) into c
                  select new
                      {
                         XaxisVal = c.Key,
                         AggreMeasure = c.Average(--column name --),
                     }).ToList();
```

`AggreMeasure = c.Average(--column name --)`,
In this line in place of "Average", user selected aggregate has to be used dynamically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make aggregate function in single method using linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371586/how-to-make-aggregate-function-in-single-method-using-linq) See also [Dynamic LINQ aggregates on IQueryable as a single query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21634630/215552).

Comment: is it possible to use directly similar to dynamic property passing as a column?